# what is mean by "__empty_global_delete"

Tags: c++, disassembly

This command is used for disassembly of visual studio 2019.

"__empty_global_delete" appears when calling the function. What does this mean?

```
private:
    int A_num;
    int A_sum;
public:
    void fun1() { printf("fun1\n"); }
};

class B : public A {
private:
    int B_num;
    int B_sum;
public:
    void fun2() { printf("fun1\n"); }
};

void fun3() {
    printf("fun3\n");
}

int main(void) {
    B b;
    b.fun1();
    b.fun2();
    fun3();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]